# Google Analytics Custom Events and parameters

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-4, flutterflow

[image]I have custom events set and they are reflected on Analytics Dashboard. But my parameters that I am sending is not getting reflected. I want to create a explore retort. Do I need google tag manager to collect custom parameters? Is there a way to do it without Tag Manager?

FYI: I am sending these events from flutterflow, which is a low code tool.

Comment: Can you show how you sending the parameters?

Comment: I am adding a screenshot to the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to check do you set up the custom event parameter in the GA4 UI.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10075209#zippy=%2Ccreate-an-event-scoped-custom-dimension%2Canalyze-an-event-scoped-custom-dimension

[image]

---

The new way to see custom event parameter now is config the code to send the parameter along with the event. But still need to setting up in the GA4 UI in setting too.